# UPI integration for different Banks

Tags: upi

I have tried to create a UPI payment mobile application(similar to BHIM). I have gone through the below documents and articles..

http://www.npci.org.in/documents/Draft-%20Annexure%20A%20Unified%20Payment%20Interface%20-%20Common%20Library%20Specifications.pdf

http://www.npci.org.in/documents/UPI-Linking-Specs-ver-1.1_draft.pdf

http://www.npci.org.in/documents/Unified-Payment-Interface-API-Technology-Specifications-v11.pdf

As per my understanding, the NPCI has provided the common UPI library sandbox access but without connect with banks we cannot use this.

My questions,

for example, I will contact with "Bank A" and get UPI library access and develop the app so My applicaiton now supports to create and use Bank A UPI/VPA.I want to use/create the UPI address from anothwe Bank B as a payer..

Is the same UPI library support for all the banks?

Is it possbile to create UPI for different bank customers?

Do I need to contact with different banks for getting diffrent library? (Bank A and Bank b)

THanks in advance for your advices.

Answer (score 5):

First of all UPI Common Library is actually a secure component that is common across all the bank apps.From security aspect, as per RBI guidelines, only the banks certified on UPI have access to UPI common library.The only dependency for the library is on the OS type i.e. Android or IOS.

Lets say, you want to create a UPI app like BHIM, you first create a basic app, test it in sandbox, on board with a bank A and do a complete certification process. Now your app will be providing VPA @bankA. 
Now you want to have a handle @bankB, so you simply on board and go through the documentation process with bank B and UPI and get the same configured.

This has no effect on UPI common library as it is a common secure package integrated with the apps.

Answer (score 1):

A little bit late and not at all expert in `upi` matter but looking at the current scenarios at least I have some views on the matter that I want to share here.

I know SO is more about providing facts as answer rather than views/opinions but as there is no answer yet for the question, I guess nothing is wrong in sharing some viewpoints here:

Each and every bank that supports UPI up till now, provides app for upi payments to their customers. In terms of UPI, these banks are called `PSP (Payment Service Provider)`.

Now, if you want to develop an third party **app** in which a customer can authorize his/her bank account and can **create UPI** for that particular account, you need to **access library or APIs** for that particular **PSP**, of course in addition to use the common upi library provided by NPCI.

But if you just want to avail UPI as a **Payment option** in your app (i.e. Paytm)
you don't need the APIs from PSPs as transaction  and authorization will be done by the Upi App provided by respective PSP.

Hope it helps! Please correct me if I misunderstood something.

Thank you!